# Automating Excel task

Tags: excel, powershell, automation

Boo is coder here but trying to learn this again. This is practical for my job as well so hopefully I can learn this all on the fly in the timeframe I have with powershell

What I’m looking to do at a high level is take a downloaded file (it’s literally “file” extension) and parse it and saved as xls extension

Actual steps I’ve broken it down to

1. script will detect this “file” extension in specified folder
2. opens file with excel program
3. selects Column A so every row is highlighted ( excel macro hits limits with this file so not an option)
4. text to columns function is selected and uses the comma delimiter
5. finish

I think if I can get the hang of that I can maybe add to it.

How do I take this conceptual idea into actual powershell code?

Comment: Can you attempt a minimal solution?

Answer (score 0):

So, your "file" is actually a CSV file with a comma delimiter and your Excel expects a different delimiter and because of that puts everything in one single column.

The delimiter used by Excel depends on the system current regional settings and in your case Excel probably wants a semi-colon.

Try converting the CSV like this:

```
$downloadedFile = 'X:\DownloadPath\something.file'
Import-Csv -Path $downloadedFile | Export-Csv -Path $downloadedFile -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

You can also detect/set the delimiter used by your Excel manually using this:

```
$downloadedFile = 'X:\DownloadPath\something.file'
$delim = [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator
Import-Csv -Path $downloadedFile | Export-Csv -Path $downloadedFile -Delimiter $delim -NoTypeInformation
```

After this, you can simply open the files in Excel by double-clicking them and the data will be in the correct columns (no need for 'text to columns')